# Reading/writing cookies between /NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net

To set a cookie in .NET you have to use:

`Response.Cookies("something")("something") = [value]`

but in JavaScript it's just

`document.cookie = [name] + "=" + [value]`

How do you write one in JS then read it in .NET (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, silly me - in .NET you can use just

```
Response.Cookies("something").Value = [value]
```